# What happens if I capture less amount than the authorize one(Paypal)?

Tags: paypal

I have to provide a solution using DoDirectPayment API Operation (Website Payments Pro) wherein the user is authorized for a particular amount and depending upon the service provided to him, the amount will be captured at a later stage but only once. I have following query before I finalized the implementation I am going to have:

Suppose I use the one time Capture method - What happens if I capture only $10 though I authorize the Card for $20? Does it make sense? OR should I go for partial capture feature of the paypal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, from what I understand that is precisely what you would need to do. Here is more information on PayPal Auth/Capture: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/auth-capture/

From the website:

Once an authorization has been made, you can:

- Capture either a partial amount or the full amount of the authorization.
- Reauthorize for a different amount — You can reauthorize for up to 115% of the originally authorized amount, not to exceed an increase of $75 USD.
- Void the authorization, if you need to cancel the transaction.